# Scrollbar issue : Datepicker in Modal Iframe

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap datepicker in Iframe which opens in bootstrap modal.

**Below is a page which opens modal popup with iframe:**

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>           
            <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-default">Open</a>
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <h4 id="myModalTitle" class="modal-title"></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <iframe src="Webform2.aspx" frameborder="0" width="100%"></iframe>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**and here is datepicker page which is opened in ifame:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('.date-picker').datepicker({
             keyboardNavigation: false,
             forceParse: false,
             calendarWeeks: false,
             autoclose: true,
             clearBtn: true,
             disableTouchKeyboard: true
              });
       });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" CssClass="date-picker"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
        </form>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
      
    </body>
    </html>
```

Now, when popup page is opened and we open a datepicker in textbox then it adds scrollbar to iframe. My date textbox is at the bottom of popup page and I do not want to increase Iframe height. Is there a way we can avoid scrollbar and datepicker is shown beyond popup box.

Thank you.